# Переход между окнами Swift macOS

Tags: swift, gui, macos

Только начинаю программировать на Swift. С консолью разобрался, получилось написать простую однооконную программу. Подскажите как переключаться между окнами (по нажатию на кнопку содержимое окна изменялось). Программу пишу под десктоп, что не гуглю все на iOS выводит.

Comment: Почему собственно начали учиться с десктопных приложений? Очень странное решение, под MacOS очень мало информации.

Comment: "Переключиться между окнами" (аналог нажатия ⌘~) и "по нажатию на кнопку содержимое окна поменялось" – это совсем разные вещи. Так что именно вы имеете в виду?